# For how many days was the Ramayana war fought?

Tags: ramayana, scripture, history, rama

The Mahabharata war is famous for its 18 days. However, the number of days the Ramayana war lasted isn't so popularly discussed as the Mahabharata war.

So, for how many days was the Ramayana war fought?

On which [tithi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithi) (lunar day) did it start and finish?

Comment: According to Padma Purana, duration of war is 87 Days in which 15 Days there was no war. So, actual war fought for 72 Days. If you want, then I can post answer on it. (But personally, I do not believe this description because according to this theory, the war didn't end on Vijayadashami.)

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani yes, just after posting this question... I read that Padma Purana says Ramayana happened for 87 days... but I didn't posted it as answer because it contradicts many things like Vijaya Dashami, also astronomical dating... living period of Sita in palace of Ravana... etc.. so I didn't posted as answer... however if you want you can post it as answer...

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani but one more interesting thing of that part of Padma Purana is that it describes in very detail... it gives every tithi in great detail... butI also think war ending on Vijaya Dashami may just be a rumour or be in previous Kalpa... because Rama was given 14 yrs vanavasa just in his birth day... sohe returned Ayodhya in just 14 years (exactly)... so he should return on Chaitra shukla Navami... but if he won Ravana in Vijaya Dashami he would return earlier...

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani also I don't know which type of calendar he used... solar or lunar... if lunar calendar then 14 yrs may complete earlier.. so Vijaya Dashami might be possible... also I don't know how they counted Adhika Maasa and Kshaya maasa...

Comment: Yes, and also they are starting month with `Shukla Paksha` instead of traditional `Krishna Paksha`.

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the Puranas, the Ramayana War was fought for a total of **87 days** with occasional halts for a period of 15 days, thus making the number of days of actual fighting 72.

The starting tithi is: **Māgha Śukla Dvitīyā**
(The second tithi of the bright half of the month of Magha)

The ending tithi is: **Caitra Kṛṣṇa Caturdaśī**
(the fourteenth tithi of the dark half of Chaitra)

Quoting the relevant extract from the Padma Purana:

> **माघशुक्लद्वितीयायाश्चैत्रकृष्णचतुर्दशीम्**। **सप्ताशीति**दिनेष्वेव मध्यं पंचदशाहकम्॥६८॥ युद्धावहारः संग्रामो द्वासप्तति दिनान्यभूत्।
>
> During the **eighty seven days** of the war which began on the **second day of the bright half of Māgha** and continued up to the **fourteenth day of the dark half of Caitra**, there was a cessation of hostilities for fifteen days, thus the (actual) war took place for seventy-two days. 
> — *Padma Purāṇa Pātāla Khaṇḍa Adhyāya 36*, Verses 68-69a

---

Notes:

1. Exactly same verses are found in the currently available Skanda Purana too. One can locate it in Chapter 30 of the Dharmaranya Khanda of the Brahma Khanda of the Skanda Purana.
2. A reading of the chapter and the dates, reveals that the dates are as per the amanta panchanga (month ending with Amavasya, and new month starting from Shukla paksha, like the South Indian one but unlike the present North Indian one where Krishna Paksha comes first)

Comment: 87 days seems too fanciful even for Ravana; plus Ravana of Valmiki gives Sita only two months of waiting period, and so a war of 87 days would mean that the two month waiting period is not known to the author of the Padma Purana account.

Comment: @Surya I’d like to cut off 30 days from the thing. Will be coming up with a question on it soon- Valmiki vs Padma Purana one month difference. Anyway, the Padma Purana gives wonderful details of all dates in fact for all things that happened in the war as well as the days Hanuman was in Lanka for. If Ravana is busy strategising in the war, he wouldn’t be bothering about the time limit given to Sitaji so the 87 days logic can’t apply here.

Comment: maybe we can message in the chatroom?  Plus, I personally feel Padma Purana is talking about Ramayana that occurred at a different time period, and not our era's Ramayana.

Comment: @Surya Nope it’s talking about this one only because there’s another chapter dedicated to Ramayana of a previous kalpa. We can message in the chatroom but I can reply to you after two days since I’m banned. Also which chatroom? Room for ram and Rickross or caste system one or the main Hindu chatroom?

Comment: main chatroom I guess. Also you're banned?? What does that mean?

Comment: @Surya it means i can’t send messages for 1 day 9 hours or so on any chat. Or you can do one thing. Click on the take messages to chat from here only. Well create another room maybe? Till that too gets frozen?

Comment: @Surya are you Sri Vaishnava? Can you answer this question I edited today? Really want to know more about this topic in the Uttarakanda : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43390/how-has-the-killing-of-shambuka-been-described-by-the-sri-vaishnava-tradition-an

Comment: I'm not allowed to open a chat room with you; and no unfortunately I'm not a Srivaishnava, so I can't offer a viewpoint on Shambuka.

Comment: now are you unbanned, to discuss the Aranya Kanda conundrum?

Comment: So that was the one month difference question...