# How has the killing of Shambuka been described by the Sri Vaishnava tradition and what reason/justification, if any, has been given for the same

Tags: ramayana, rama, sri-vaishnava, divya-prabhandham

As per [this site](https://4000divyaprabandham.wordpress.com/category/4-kulasekara-alwar/), Kulasekara Azhwar *indicates* the incident of Shri [Rama killing Shambuka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/why-did-r%C4%81ma-kill-%C5%9Aamb%C5%ABka-and-is-r%C4%81ma-justified-in-killing-him-without-a-second/28087#28087) in verse 749 in the 10th dashakam of Perumal Tirumozhi of the [Muthalayiram](http://acharya.org/dp/1/index.html) of the [Nalayira Divya Prabandham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naalayira_Divya_Prabandham). The relevant verse is:

> செறிதவச் சம்புகன்  தன்னைச் சென்று கொன்று செழுமறையோன் உயிர் மீட்டுத் தவத்தோன் ஈந்த
> ceṟitavac campukaṉ  taṉṉaic ceṉṟu koṉṟu ceḻumaṟaiyōṉ uyir
> mīṭṭut tavattōṉ īnta
>
> My sweet Lord Rama went and slew Shambuka of terrible penance, gave life to the dead Vedic seer. <sup>Note 2</sup>

One can listen to the above verse of the Perumal Tirumozhi at 50:23 onwards in [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MyMyS3wJnm8)

**Questions:**

1. Does the Sri Vaishnava tradition (scriptures and commentaries, not necessarily on Valmiki Ramayana) record the incident in detail and if yes, are there any variations from the Ramayana and Puranas, (where Shambuka is killed merely because he was a shudra ascetic/ wanted to attain heaven with his mortal body); for example was he an asura and not Shudra human? <sup>Note 1</sup>
2. What is the Sri Vaishnava justification/ view with regard to this incident, irrespective of any variation from the Ramayana and Puranas? (Also in case there is no variation how is the killing explained/justified just because he was merely a Shudra)

---

Notes:

1. Had read on a Tamil site which I can’t find that Shambuka was actually an asura named Jambuka (both written as cambuka in Tamil) and not a human Shudra (the upside down penance can give a clue as to this fact). His being an asura and a Brahmin dying makes more sense.
2. Translation from [here](https://archive.org/details/thesacredbookoffourthousand01nalayiradivyaprabandhamsriramabharati2000/page/n157/mode/2up)
3. I don’t understand Tamil

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115835/discussion-on-question-by-archit-how-has-the-killing-of-shambuka-been-described).

Comment: Yes all scholars accepts that Lord Rama did indeed slay sambhu of evil mind he wanted to be become lord of indra which is shiva himself and attain devi parvati the intention of tapas was totally adharmic so he was executed

Comment: There were several instanceclike this in krishna avatra he kills washernan who denies lord krishna of royal robes from the outer its seems that Wasserman us at no fault as he is just following king but internally details that lord only knows  Vali is another instance

Comment: According to Sri Vaishnava scholar MA Alwar, as the Ramayana says, he was killed because he was doing prohibited tapas as a Shudra. But MA Alwar also says that because of his spiritual inclination, he was reborn as a Brahman to continue with the tapas.

Comment: Well two people can’t be tagged so.... **PrasannaR** was Shambuka of evil mind an asura?2. **Ikshvaku**, What source does MA Alwar use? Valmiki or some other one? What do traditional acharyas like Ramanuja etc say?. We spoke about this before and remember I told you I can’t digest the Shudra aspect it doesn’t fit in the description given. It seems completely out of place

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43650/19211
Does this answer your question?
I dont think we need to stick to Tradition's opinion though

Comment: @SethuSrivastsaKoduru, no I’ve read and upvoted it. The question is different. Here the question doesn’t want to go by the Ramayana puranic tradition. We want to see if we’re missing something. Eg was he an asura. **Sri Vaishnava will hopefully give us a very authentic picture without any caste bias** etc. Saw the quora also it’s nice.

Comment: for this you need to go BG where he clarifies humans beings as 2 types devia and asura yeva cha.. in deiva and asura vibhaga yoga.. he mention qualities of asura..please check

Comment: @PrasannaR okay thank you I’ll check that. Accha them again, they don’t say in Ramayana that he was of asuric quality. Just because he was Shudra doesn’t mean he’s asuric? He may have tamo Guna predominance (enjoying partying drinking alcohol etc) but Shudra =/= asura though he may have qualities. I’m saying was he actually an asura - like a rakshasa by birth etc?

Comment: Asura term can be contextual one who is exhibiting  tamasic qualities is an asura even tough he be born brahmin here he did intense penance for dethroning lord shiva that is adharmic totally this is obviously entice punishment of severe order where it is non obvious Wasserman punishment see would you be able know anybody intention except lord

Comment: @Archit, Sudra doesn't mean Asura. Krishna in chapter 16(please read whole chapter, to be specific verses 15-18) says that people think they are high born wealthy and perform sacrifises in name. Are demonic. Obviously he is refering to corrupt dwijas. Aswatthama and Vidura compare them. Duryodhana and Yudhistira. In fact Krishna says I come from age to age to destory wicked people. Then he should have come to destory Sudras  if we use this logic. But who were destoryed ? Foolish bad Ksatriyas.

Comment: Also please read Gita 16.3 commentary by Swami Sivananda. All Devine qualities Krishna lists , Sivananda Swami identifies them with all Varnas. Kshama and Dhriti are the special alities or Dharmas of the Kshatriyas (warrior class). These are the Sattvic alities of Kshatriyas. Saucham and Adroha are the special Dharmas of the Vaisyas. They are the Sattvic alities of the Vaisyas (merchant class). Absence of pride is the special Dharma of the Sudras (servant class). It is a Sattvic ality that belongs to the Sudras.The divine wealth or Daivi Sampat consists of twentysix attributes.

Comment: @Archit Whats your review on Indian Philosophy by SN Dasgupta the thing on Wisdom Lib

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru you’re giving me too much to read I’m not gonna land up reading so much:D. Who’s SN Dasgupta?

Comment: Lol where I gave so much to read? 
THis guy https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-1
@Archit